# How to add static text and hover text over image at the same time using CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

Dears,
I'm using the code below to show list of images from database and showing some text (also from DB) over the images when hover.
I need to keep the current settings but to also add one more text (from DB) but to be shown always (static) over the image:

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
width:100px;
display:block;
}
.text {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
color:#333;
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
width: 500px;
font-size:18px;
height: 100%;
line-height:100px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 10;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text:hover {
opacity:1;
}


.img {
z-index:1;
}

.grid {
position:relative;
float:left;
width: 500px;
height:333px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-right: 10px; 
border: 0;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Code:

```
foreach($dbrow as $row) {

?>
<div class="grid">
    <a href="<?php echo $row['hotel_url']; ?>" class="wrapper">
        <span class="text">
            <b><?php echo $row['name']; ?></b>
            <br/>
            <?php echo $row['desc_en']; ?>
            <br/>
            <i>Book Now</i>
        </span>
        <img align="center" src="<?php echo $row['photo_url']; ?>">
    </a>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change a bit your HTML using HTML5 so the span remains the same (although I would change it as well without using br) and both the image and the caption are wrapped under the HTML5 figure tag.

```
<a href="#">
  <span class="text">Hover text</span>
  <figure>
    <img src="#" alt="foo" width=500 height=400>
    <figcaption>
      Text underneath
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

Comment: This shows the text below the image. But I want it to be over it. Exactly as the hover text but without hover.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
.text { display: none; }
.text:hover { display: block }
```

Comment: Because I needed to add background colour and also some styling. And I need to fetch all data from the database.
I don't have problem with hover text, I just need to add extra text to shown always (without hover)

Comment: Then the text you always want to be visible, should just be a different span or label element, with different styling.

Comment: It didn't work for me, it was always shown above the image or below it, but not over it.
If you can give me an example by code I would appreciate it.
Thank you